# How to format legend title to font type monospace in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to format the legend title to be monospace.  I have:

```
    width = 8
    print_slope     = "{0:.5F}".format(slope)
    print_intercept = "{0:.5F}".format(intercept)
    print_r_squared = "{0:.5F}".format(r_value**2)
    ax.legend(prop={'family': 'monospace'},title='Slope:     '+str(print_slope.rjust(width))+'\nIntercept: '+str(print_intercept.rjust(width))+'\nR-squared: '+str(print_r_squared.rjust(width)))
```

Yet the output I get gives me the legend title in variable width, with the series in monospace:

[image]

How do I get the title to be monospace also?  Thanks.

Comment: I should add this is with Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 4):

I think you can set the legend's title with a separate call.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], 'k-', label='data')
leg = ax.legend(prop={'size': 20})
leg.set_title('Legend Title', prop={'size': 14, 'weight': 'heavy'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword argument `title_fontproperties` of `legend()`:

```
ax.legend(..., title_fontproperties={'family': 'monospace'})
```